# Disable "Install from directory" option at Joomla's 2.5 extension manager

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

How can i disable the option "Install from Directory" at Extension Manager in Joomla 2.5 ?

The reason is that if for someone click by mistake Install button at that option, the website is "destroyed"....

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by destroyed? The install from directory option is there in case you want to FTP your extension to be installed to a folder on your server, then point the install to directory at that folder location along with the file name you wish to install.

Comment: Once i clicked by mistake the "install" button at Install from Directory option, which had by default the path "mywebsite/.../.../tmp" and without pointing to specific file, and the website is lost for ever...i guess it installed all the temp files in that folder.

Comment: Strange, this is not the default behavior for Joomla. The way that portion of the system is designed is to look for the specified extension in the form field, and even then that extension must have a valid manifest file to install.

By default there is no way to actually disable this functionality by default without modifying core files in the joomla administrator folder. Changing those files would in the long run do no good for you since the next Joomla update would more than likely revert your changes back.

Comment: Hmm that's strange i agree, but it happened, and now i am afraid that someone (from the people who upload content) may click on that by mistake and...boom take the website down...

Comment: I think the only recourse you are going to have then is to edit the core file if you really want to be able to hide that field in Joomla 2.5. If it was Joomla 2+ you could add a css declaration for your admin template that would handle it, but 2.5 does not have CSS classes assigned to the individual fields, only a shared CSS class for the upload fields to style them.